# Using the Adapter Class to synchronize data with a non-AdapterView View Group

Tags: android, list, adapter, android-linearlayout, android-adapterview

I would like to use an adapter to synchronize a List of data with a vertical LinearLayout where it will be displayed. The problem I'm having is that non-AdapterView View Groups (Like LinearLayout) do not have the setAdapter() method. Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a ListView with SimpleAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter. Both adapters are **very** flexible for all kinds of customization based on your data.

Comment: That's what I have right now. Unfortunately this list is being displayed inside a scroll view. List Views are not meant to be displayed inside scroll views.

Comment: Why not remove it from a scrollview, you could also make a custom View based on LinearLayout?

Comment: Not sure how a custom view based on a Linear Layout would help, but I need the the scroll view because the height of the the views I want to display exceeds that of the window I want to display it in.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to have two separate scollable areas, one half for list view, the other for the other widgets to scroll?

Comment: I have a specific layout in mind. I'm pretty sure that I'll end up using a LinearLayout for my list. At this point the main question is how it will be populated.